# Replace php content with div

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

When a user clicks on product image ajax send id of product to `PHP`. `PHP` find product in `MySQL` database and fills data into `HTML`.

The problem is when `PHP` fill data that data do not exist on the current page. https://ibb.co/DG1sSNz --Product data is empty

Data is stored in another page same as `index.php` (I found data in chrome network tab) https://ibb.co/3SVmyQb

How can I solve this problem? And btw this is a `wordpress` site.

This is `jquery` code with ajax

```
$(document).on("click touchend", ".product_stake_stapovi, .product_invalidska_kolica, .product_antidekubitni_program, .product_ortoze, .product_mideri, .product_pojas, .product_toaletni_program, .product_bolnicki_kreveti_i_oprema", function (event) {
        var product_num_id = $(this).children(".num_id").attr("id"); //Getting id from image element (that is location of real stored id in database)
        var product_id = $(this).attr("class");
        var product_real_id = product_id.replace("col-3 col ", ""); 
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "index.php?proizvodi",
            data: ({product_num_id:product_num_id}),
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(product_num_id);
                $(".big_categoryes").fadeOut("fast");
                $(".all_products").fadeOut("fast");
                $(".product_view_info").fadeIn("smooth");

            }
        });
    });
```

```php
if(isset($_POST["product_num_id"])) { //ini_set('display_errors',1); //error_reporting(-1); $servername = "localhost"; $username = "medit105_admin"; $password = "s*ib#^Z*3pkL"; $database = "medit105_meditalis"; $dbc = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database); //Konekcija na server - bazu podataka mysqli_query($dbc, "SET NAMES utf8"); mysqli_query($dbc, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); mysqli_query($dbc, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION='utf8_unicode_ci'"); #Provera konekcije: if(!$dbc) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); } $product_num_id = $_POST["product_num_id"]; $q = "SELECT * FROM meditalis_proizvodi WHERE id = '$product_num_id'"; $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q); if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) { while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>

<ul class="product">
    <li><img src="wp-content/themes/meditalis-to-wp/assets/products/<?php echo $row[" image "]; ?>" alt=" Product Photo"></li>
    <li class="informations">
        <div class="product_name">
            <h4><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h4></div>
        <div class="desc_info">
            <p>
                <?php echo $row["description"]; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <img src="wp-content/themes/meditalis-to-wp/assets/products/<?php echo $row[" size_img "]; ?>" alt="Size Photo">
    </li>
</ul>

<?php }
}
//echo $product_num_id;
mysqli_close($dbc);
exit();
}
```

It's possible to replace data from a new page to the current page on screen without a refreshing page?

EDIT:  Ok, I put PHP on top of the page and run jquery inside PHP.I used json_encode for variables and try to fill data to HTML with jquery. But now jquery want run and php want pull data from database(idk why).

```
        $product_image = "";
        $product_name = "";
        $product_description = "";
        $product_size = "";

        if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { 

                $product_image = "wp-content/themes/meditalis-to-wp/assets/products/" . $row["image"];
                $product_name = $row["name"];
                $product_description = $row["description"];
                $product_size = "wp-content/themes/meditalis-to-wp/assets/products/" . $row["img_size"];


                echo '<script>';
                echo 'var product_image = ' . json_encode($product_image) . ';';
                echo 'var product_name = ' . json_encode($product_name) . ';';
                echo 'var product_description = ' . json_encode($product_description) . ';';
                echo 'var product_size = ' . json_encode($product_size) . ';';
                echo 'alert("dbg");';
                echo '$("#product_name_put").html(product_name);';
                echo '$("#product_desc_put").html(product_description);';
                echo '$("#product_image_put").attr("src", product_image);';
                echo '$("#product_size_put").attr("src", product_size);';
                echo '</script>'; 

            }
        }
```

This is output in network tab: var product_image = "wp-content/themes/meditalis-to-wp/assets/products/invalidska kolica/KOLICA MEHANIcKA EXCEL PLUS.jpg";var product_name = "Kolica mehanicka excel plus";var product_description = "Standardna mehani\u010dka kolica
\r\n\u0160irine sedi\u0161ta 36-40-43-46-50 cm
\r\nStranice: preklopive
\r\nTo\u010dkovi: pune gume napred i pozadi
\r\nTe\u017eina kolica : 16kg
\r\nNosivost kolica : 120kg
\r\nProizvo\u0111a\u010d: MOVI, Italija
\r\n";var product_size = "wp-content/themes/meditalis-to-wp/assets/products/";alert("dbg");$("#product_name_put").html(product_name);$("#product_desc_put").html(product_description);$("#product_image_put").attr("src", product_image);$("#product_size_put").attr("src", product_size);

Answer (score 0):

Your will get `HTML` on ajax response. Then you can use that Ajax response in your Ajax success function and can append that wherever you want as below:

```
$(document).on("click touchend", ".product_stake_stapovi, .product_invalidska_kolica, .product_antidekubitni_program, .product_ortoze, .product_mideri, .product_pojas, .product_toaletni_program, .product_bolnicki_kreveti_i_oprema", function (event) {
        var product_num_id = $(this).children(".num_id").attr("id"); //Getting id from image element (that is location of real stored id in database)
        var product_id = $(this).attr("class");
        var product_real_id = product_id.replace("col-3 col ", ""); 
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "index.php?proizvodi",
            data: ({product_num_id:product_num_id}),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data) //It will have your HTML, you can use this HTML wherever you want.
                //console.log(product_num_id);
                $(".big_categoryes").fadeOut("fast");
                $(".all_products").fadeOut("fast");
                $(".product_view_info").fadeIn("smooth");

            }
        });
    });
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: But data is full ```html``` code of new page.How to get only ```div (.product_view_info)``` element?

Comment: In your PHP file, just create HTML which you need and add an exit function after that. After this, you will only  receive the required HTML in your ajax response.

Comment: I don't know if you saw it, but I've done it before

Comment: You need to create a separate PHP file for ajax.I am assuming that your index.php file also have other HTML data. So create a new PHP file as getProductData.php which will only have PHP code. Also please ensure to remove commented code.

Comment: I can't do like that because the website is on wordpress

Comment: Then add your Post function on top of the page. so it will not have any other HTML code.

Comment: Ok, I put PHP on top of the page and run jquery inside PHP.I used ```json_encode``` for variables and try to fill data to HTML with jquery. But now jquery want run and php want pull data from database(idk why).