# Send php variables to jquery function

Tags: php, jquery

Ok, I need to send data from PHP to jquery and use jquery function to update that data into HTML.
But the problem is jquery want update HTML elements with PHP data...

This is php code.Php is called from ajax.

```php
    $product_image = "";
        $product_name = "";
        $product_description = "";
        $product_size = "";

        if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { 

                $product_image = "wp-content/themes/meditalis-to-wp/assets/products/" . $row["image"];
                $product_name = $row["name"];
                $product_description = $row["description"];
                $product_size = "wp-content/themes/meditalis-to-wp/assets/products/" . $row["img_size"];


                echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">';
                echo 'var product_image = ' . json_encode($product_image) . ';';
                echo 'var product_name = ' . json_encode($product_name) . ';';
                echo 'var product_description = ' . json_encode($product_description) . ';';
                echo 'var product_size = ' . json_encode($product_size) . ';';
                echo 'showProduct();';
                echo '</script>'; 

            }
        }
        //echo $product_num_id;
        mysqli_close($dbc);
        exit();
    }
```

This is jquery function for updating html elemtns:

```
function showProduct()
{
    alert("dbg");
    $("#product_name_put").html(product_name);
    $("#product_desc_put").html(product_description);
    $("#product_image_put").attr("src", product_image);
    $("#product_size_put").attr("src", product_size);
}
```

And this is html elements:

```
<div class="product_view_info">
                    <ul class="product">
                        <li><img id="product_image_put" src="" alt=" Product Photo"></li>
                        <li class="informations">
                            <div class="product_name"><h4 id="product_name_put"></h4></div>
                            <div class="desc_info"><p id="product_desc_put"></p></div>
                            <img id="product_size_put" src="" alt="Size Photo">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

This is a problem: https://ibb.co/HGyJkwB

**UPDATE**:  AJAX CODE: When user click on product ajax sending id of clicked product to php.

```
    $(document).on("click touchend", ".product_stake_stapovi, .product_invalidska_kolica, .product_antidekubitni_program, .product_ortoze, .product_mideri, .product_pojas, .product_toaletni_program, .product_bolnicki_kreveti_i_oprema", function (event) {
        var product_num_id = $(this).children(".num_id").attr("id"); //Getting id from image element (that is location of real stored id in database)
        var product_id = $(this).attr("class");
        var product_real_id = product_id.replace("col-3 col ", ""); 
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "index.php?proizvodi",
            data: ({product_num_id:product_num_id}),
            success: function() {
                $(".big_categoryes").fadeOut("fast");
                $(".all_products").fadeOut("fast");
                $(".product_view_info").fadeIn("smooth");

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where is your jQuery AJAX code?

Comment: Why you need ajax code.I know ajax is working...

Comment: You'd be better to send your data as JSON, rather than sending multiple scripts.

Comment: Also, you're using the same ID multiple times. This won't work.

Comment: I use ajax for sending id of clicked product to php.and thats work fine.

Comment: You don't have a return parameter in your ajax success function. As such your returned data isn't being used.

Comment: Then how I can show data? I already try to show data with only php but php return data into new page. and when ajax get data in success function that is full html page...

Comment: The first thing to do is to change `success: function()` to `success: function(data)`. Then add a line to success function `console.log(data);

Then let me know if you get your return data on the console.

Comment: I already tell you: data is full html page: https://ibb.co/F63T0Ry

Comment: Please. I'm trying to help you. Please do what I have suggested. This will validate a few things for me. At present your code is not using your response from your ajax call. It cannot, because you don't have a parameter in your success function!

Comment: I did what you wanted.I just use alert instead of console.log

Comment: ok. So you now know that your ajax mechanism is working. However, you are getting a full page back, if you console.log then you will see all of it, not just the top part. There may be an error. Please use console.log instead.

Comment: Look, I already asked questions about this topic and I checked that everything was fine.Console log will show full page and bcs of that I use json encode!!! You can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646127/replace-php-content-with-div/57646208?noredirect=1#comment101744026_57646208

Comment: I'm trying to help. Your return data should contain just your php output. But it's a full page. There is a problem. Bye

Comment: No that is not problem.Ajax sends successfully id to php and php need to send variables to jquery. only jquery is problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can get data from PHP as json like so:

```
    if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { 

        $product = (object)[];

        $product->image = "wp-content/themes/meditalis-to-wp/assets/products/" . $row["image"];
        $product->name = $row["name"];
        $product->description = $row["description"];
        $product->size = "wp-content/themes/meditalis-to-wp/assets/products/" . $row["img_size"];

        echo json_encode($product);


    }
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
exit();
```

and get data from json with jquery:

```
 $(document).on("click touchend", ".product_stake_stapovi, .product_invalidska_kolica, .product_antidekubitni_program, .product_ortoze, .product_mideri, .product_pojas, .product_toaletni_program, .product_bolnicki_kreveti_i_oprema", function (event) {
    var product_num_id = $(this).children(".num_id").attr("id"); //Getting id from image element (that is location of real stored id in database)
    var product_id = $(this).attr("class");
    var product_real_id = product_id.replace("col-3 col ", ""); 
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "index.php?proizvodi",
        data: ({product_num_id:product_num_id}),
        success: function(response) {

            var product = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(product.image);// example
            showProduct(product);

            $(".big_categoryes").fadeOut("fast");
            $(".all_products").fadeOut("fast");
            $(".product_view_info").fadeIn("smooth");

        }
    });
});

function showProduct(product){

    $("#product_name_put").html(product.name);
    $("#product_desc_put").html(product.description);
    $("#product_image_put").attr("src", product.image);
    $("#product_size_put").attr("src", product.size);
}
```

I hope this could help you.